# When I try to login with an account from my database, my ajax call won't enter on the succes event. Has anyone any suggestion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, routes

Here is where I define the loginData as an empty object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('login');
        $('#login').on('click', function() {
            let loginData = {};
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input').each(function() {
                loginData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
            })
```

And here it is my ajax call which only enters on the error event.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:'text',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(loginData),
        encode: true,
        succes: function() {
            console.log('succes');
            window.location.href = '/index';
            $("#email_error_message").hide();
            $(".email-input").css("border-bottom","1px solid #34f458");
            $("#password_error_message").hide();
            $(".pass-input").css("border-bottom","1px solid #34f458");
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            let error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            $('.email-input').css({"border":"1px solid red", "color":"red"})
            $('.pass-input').css({"border":"1px solid red", "color":"red"})
            $('#email_error_message').html("Wrong email or password").css({"color":"red"});
            $("#email_error_message").show();

        }
    });
});
```

});

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the console for errors and post them as part of your question

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.  

This is the only thing that shows in the console.

Comment: Change `async: false,` to `async: true,` or remove it entirely because the default is `true`.